# Store JRE version through command line

Tags: command-line

I have a scenario where I need to store the only JRE version through the command line and redirect the same to another output text file.

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is to stderr you have to redirect stderr:

```
java -version 2>path/to/result/file
```

If you want just the version number:

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]+" >path/to/result/file
```

(the above works at least for Oracle, OpenJDK and IBM versions)